# Label is not filled completely

Tags: python, image, tkinter, text, label

I have the following problem: I am currently writing a program in python that uses labels to contain an image and a text. The program itself works correctly, but the labels mess up the graphics for me. To put the image in the label behind the text I use the option `compound = tkinter.CENTER`. The problem with this is that the image no longer fills the entire label due to the centering. This creates white borders around the label (it is not the borderline. I already tried to set it 0 but it didn't work. I also set it to 2 once and saw that it includes the unwanted white spaces around it). I should also add, that i use the same picture for labels at the moment, but that shouldn't be the problem here right? I only know this way to display a text in front of an image in a label and I am getting really frustrated because I can't find another solution. Due to the code it is kind of necessary to use labels in this case. I isolated the problem and just posted a small piece of code here that represents it because my program is just too big to post it in its entirety.

```
import tkinter

win = tkinter.Tk()
win.geometry("1280x720")

photo = tkinter.PhotoImage(file = "orange.png")

testLabel = tkinter.Label(win, compound = tkinter.CENTER, text = "Test", image = photo, bd = 0)
testLabel.place(x = 30, y = 30, anchor = "nw")

otherLabel = tkinter.Label(win, compound = tkinter.CENTER, text = "Other", image = photo, bd = 0)
otherLabel.place(x = 50, y = 50, anchor = "nw")

win.mainloop()
```

As soon as I remove the `compound = tkinter.CENTER` part the white spaces are gone but then the text is again not visible.
Can someone please help me?

Comment: Try setting `width` and `height` of the label to be the same as that of the image.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the label width and height to fixed values as suggested in the comment the label won't be the size adapted to the length and size of the label text. To keep the label adapting to the text length and size create the label with the text first, then use its by tkinter set width and height to keep its size when adding a background image to it. **If the image is large enough** there will be no space in the label without the image background. See the code below where the `testLabel` has an in advance set size and the `otherLabel` adapts its height and width to the length and size of the text placed in it:

```
import tkinter

win = tkinter.Tk()
win.geometry("480x320")

photo = tkinter.PhotoImage(file = "orange.png")

testLabel = tkinter.Label(win, compound = tkinter.CENTER, text = "Test", image = photo, bd = 0, width=50, height=15)
testLabel.place(x = 30, y = 30, anchor = "nw")

otherLabel = tkinter.Label(win, compound = tkinter.CENTER, text = "Other Test Text", bd = 0, font=('',14) )
otherLabel.place(x = 50, y = 50, anchor = "nw")
otherLabel.update()
otherLabel.config(image=photo, width=otherLabel.winfo_width(), height=otherLabel.winfo_height())

win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

> but the labels mess up the graphics for me. To put the image in the
> label behind the text....

To fix problem.

Change:

```
otherLabel.place(x = 50, y = 50, anchor = "nw")
```

to:

```
otherLabel.place(x = 320, y = 50, anchor = "nw"
```

Screenshot. you can see both images and labels:

[image]