# I am trying to make guessing game in Python Tkinter. But I don't get the result I what. what's the problem?

Tags: python, tkinter

here's the code:

```
from tkinter import * 
import random
win = Tk()
win.geometry("500x500") 
win.title('Guessing Game')
TARGET = random.randint(1,5)
guess = IntVar()
output = 'hello'
def play_game():
    global guess
    global output
    if guess.get() > TARGET:
        output = 'too high'
    elif TARGET > guess.get():
        output = 'too low'
    elif TARGET == guess.get():
        output = 'Right guess'
title = Label(win,text='Guessing Game').place(anchor=CENTER,x=250,y=100)
title1 = Label(win,text='number from 1 - 5',height=10).place(anchor=CENTER,x=250,y=150)
entry = Entry(win,textvariable=guess).place(anchor=CENTER,x=250,y=200)
click = Button(win,text='Guess',command=play_game).place(anchor=CENTER,x=250,y=250)
ans = Label(win,text=TARGET).place(anchor=CENTER,x=250,y=300)
ans1 = Label(win,text=output).place(anchor=CENTER,x=250,y=350)
win.mainloop()
```

I wanted to change `ans1` text but it doesn't. I hope you understand what I am asking.

Comment: `text=output` is equivalent to `text="hello"`, so why do you expect that changing what `output` references later, would change what the button displays? use `ans1.config(text="too high")` and so on instead of `output = "too high"`

Answer (score 0):

- You need this `ans.configure`. And put this in line 21.
- In line 29, removed  parameter `text=TARGET
- In line 29 split two line instead of one line to prevent an error.

Code:

```
from tkinter import * 
import random
win = Tk()
win.geometry("500x500") 
win.title('Guessing Game')

TARGET = random.randint(1,5)
guess = IntVar()
output = 'hello'

def play_game():
    global guess
    global output
    if guess.get() > TARGET:
        output = 'too high'
    elif TARGET > guess.get():
        output = 'too low'
    elif TARGET == guess.get():
        output = 'Right guess'

    ans.configure(text=output)     
        
title = Label(win,text='Guessing Game').place(anchor=CENTER,x=250,y=100)
title1 = Label(win,text='number from 1 - 5',height=10).place(anchor=CENTER,x=250,y=150)

entry = Entry(win,textvariable=guess).place(anchor=CENTER,x=250,y=200)
click = Button(win,text='Guess',command=play_game).place(anchor=CENTER,x=250,y=250)

ans = Label(win)
ans.place(anchor=CENTER,x=250,y=300)

ans1 = Label(win,text=output).place(anchor=CENTER,x=250,y=350)

win.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Screenshot:

[image]

screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I then add a background image to it. how to make labels text without background color. now the text background is black. i want only the text, without background.

Comment: Just add parameter in Label text='Hello'

Comment: Do you mean something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72613242/label-is-not-filled-completely/75411044#75411044

Comment: yes i want like that

Comment: Can you tell me which Label ?

Comment: Just followed my link  example that I gave you.

Comment: every label. i created separate label for bg image.

Comment: Read the code line by line from link. You can try it by urself. It will help you.